# Does kubernetes do concurrent unmounts for pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I wanted to know,if a pod has more than one volume mounted to it then when we delete the pod , does kubernetes do a concurrent unmount of both the volumes ?.

Comment: My question doesnt have anything to do with any code ,I was wondering how the unmount function works and if the volume manager tries to parallelise unmounting various volumes of a pod

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a Pod, all volumes are unmounted.

As far as concurrency, I don't think this is done in parallel per-se, but I'm not sure why that would be important.